# How can i get my loop to start from "Day 1"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm trying to make a list starting from day one and moving onward, however every time i run the code it starts from the days the user inputs. It's probably an easy fix but I'm stumped. Any help would be appreciated!

```
orig = int(input("Enter the starting number of organisms: "))
days = int(input("Enter the number of days: "))
increase = float(input("Enter the daily population increase: "))
for i in range(days):
    orig = orig * (1 + increase)
    days = days + 1
    print(f'After {days} days there are {orig:.6f} organisms')
```

Comment: You need to use two variables instead of just one.  Coincidentally you already have a second variable in your code.

Comment: _however every time i run the code it starts from the days the user inputs_ No it doesn't.  The loop starts from 0.  But the loop prints `days` instead of `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

then why not using i as the day counter:

```
orig = int(input("Enter the starting number of organisms: "))
days = int(input("Enter the number of days: "))
increase = float(input("Enter the daily population increase: "))
for i in range(days):
    orig = orig * (1 + increase)
    print(f'After {i+1} days there are {orig:.6f} organisms')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
days = int(input("Enter the number of days: "))
increase = float(input("Enter the daily population increase: "))
for i in range(days):
    orig = orig * (1 + increase)
    days = days + 1
    print(f'After {i+1} days there are {orig:.6f} organisms')
```

Comment: What's the purpose of increasing the ```days``` variable?

Answer (score 0):

Changed code to track day number

```
orig = int(input("Enter the starting number of organisms: "))
days = int(input("Enter the number of days: "))
increase = float(input("Enter the daily population increase: "))
for i in range(days): # will take  on the values 0 to days -1
    orig = orig * (1 + increase)
    day_number = i + 1 # create a day number which will have the value 1 to days
    print(f'After {day_number} days there are {orig:.6f} organisms')
```

Trial run

```
Enter the starting number of organisms: 5
Enter the number of days: 5
Enter the daily population increase: .5
After 1 days there are 7.500000 organisms
After 2 days there are 11.250000 organisms
After 3 days there are 16.875000 organisms
After 4 days there are 25.312500 organisms
After 5 days there are 37.968750 organisms
```

Comment: Couldn't you simply have used ```i + 1``` without introducing a new variable?

Comment: If and when i get my Diploma, it will be thanks to you. Cheers

Comment: The new variable `day_number` was introduced to make the code more self-documenting by using it in `print(f'After {day_number} days there are {orig:.6f} organisms')` than using `print(f'After {i + 1} days there are {orig:.6f} organisms')`.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to use `i` which is increasing in the way you would want `days` to increase:

```
orig = int(input("Enter the starting number of organisms: "))
days = int(input("Enter the number of days: "))
increase = float(input("Enter the daily population increase: "))

# Starting the range from 1 makes more sense
for i in range(1, days+1):
    orig *= (1 + increase)
    print(f'After {i} days there are {orig:.6f} organisms')
```

```
Enter the starting number of organisms: 1
Enter the number of days: 5
Enter the daily population increase: 1
After 1 days there are 2.000000 organisms
After 2 days there are 4.000000 organisms
After 3 days there are 8.000000 organisms
After 4 days there are 16.000000 organisms
After 5 days there are 32.000000 organisms
```